# Using an io.WriteSeeker without a File in Go

Tags: go

I am using a third party library to generate PDFs. In order to write the PDF at the end (after all of content has been added using the lib's API), the `pdfWriter` type has a `Write` function that expects an `io.WriteSeeker`.

This is OK if I want to work with files, but I need to work in-memory. Trouble is, I can't find any way to do this - the only native type I found that implements `io.WriteSeeker` is File.

This is the part that works by using `File` for the `io.Writer` in the `Write` function of the `pdfWriter`:

```
fWrite, err := os.Create(outputPath)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

defer fWrite.Close()

err = pdfWriter.Write(fWrite)
```

Is there way to do this without an actual File? Like getting a `[]byte` or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no ready solution for an in-memory [`io.WriteSeeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#WriteSeeker) implementation in the standard lib.

But as always, you can always implement your own. It's not that hard.

An `io.WriteSeeker` is an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) and an [`io.Seeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Seeker), so basically you only need to implement 2 methods:

```
Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error)
```

Read the general contract of these methods in their documentation how they should behave.

Here's a simple implementation which uses an in-memory byte slice (`[]byte`). It's not optimized for speed, this is just a "demo" implementation.

```
type mywriter struct {
    buf []byte
    pos int
}

func (m *mywriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    minCap := m.pos + len(p)
    if minCap > cap(m.buf) { // Make sure buf has enough capacity:
        buf2 := make([]byte, len(m.buf), minCap+len(p)) // add some extra
        copy(buf2, m.buf)
        m.buf = buf2
    }
    if minCap > len(m.buf) {
        m.buf = m.buf[:minCap]
    }
    copy(m.buf[m.pos:], p)
    m.pos += len(p)
    return len(p), nil
}

func (m *mywriter) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error) {
    newPos, offs := 0, int(offset)
    switch whence {
    case io.SeekStart:
        newPos = offs
    case io.SeekCurrent:
        newPos = m.pos + offs
    case io.SeekEnd:
        newPos = len(m.buf) + offs
    }
    if newPos < 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("negative result pos")
    }
    m.pos = newPos
    return int64(newPos), nil
}
```

Yes, and that's it.

Testing it:

```
my := &mywriter{}
var ws io.WriteSeeker = my

ws.Write([]byte("hello"))
fmt.Println(string(my.buf))

ws.Write([]byte(" world"))
fmt.Println(string(my.buf))

ws.Seek(-2, io.SeekEnd)
ws.Write([]byte("k!"))
fmt.Println(string(my.buf))

ws.Seek(6, io.SeekStart)
ws.Write([]byte("gopher"))
fmt.Println(string(my.buf))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TjXBLd3E5m)):

```
hello
hello world
hello work!
hello gopher
```

**Things that can be improved:**

- Create a `mywriter` value with an initial empty `buf` slice, but with a capacity that will most likely cover the size of the result PDF document. E.g. if you estimate the result PDFs are around 1 MB, create a buffer with capacity for 2 MB like this:
  `my := &mywriter{buf: make([]byte, 0, 2<<20)}`
- Inside `mywriter.Write()` when capacity needs to be increased (and existing content copied over), it may be profitable to use bigger increment, e.g. double the current capacity to a certain extent, which reserves space for future appends and minimizes the reallocations.

Comment: What an awesome answer, thanks. Small comment: on the SeekEnd case, you need to increment the offset, not subtract it. Check out stdlib's reader.go for reference. Since I'm using this in several projects, I've made this into a lib and gave you credit in the license and readme files. Check it out: https://github.com/orcaman/writerseeker